# Image keeps jumping out of div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id = "l-leftcontainer" style="width:454px; height:300px;float:left"></div>
<div id = "l-rightcontainer" style="width:200px; height:300px;position:relative;right:0;z-index:2;overflow=hidden"> <img src="Test images/DS.png" width="200" height="200" border="0" /></div>
```

I put two divs next to each other with an image in the second one. Every time I test it, the image jumps out of the div and renders under everything else instead. I can't use float on the second div or other divs that overflow on purpose will push it. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Sorry. The formatting screwed up and didn't put my code in.

Comment: I don't understand why this was put on hold? I described the problem, posted the code, and someone gave me an answer that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align:top` instead of floating and `position:relative` + `right: 0`?

```
<div id = "l-leftcontainer" style="width:454px; height:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;border:1px solid #000;"></div>
<div id = "l-rightcontainer" style="width:200px; height:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;overflow=hidden;border:1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 0):

Simply nest the divs:

```
<div id="l-leftcontainer" style="width:454px;background:red; height:300px;">
    <div id="l-rightcontainer" style="background:blue;width:200px; height:300px;"> <img src="Test images/DS.png" style="" width="200" height="200" border="0"></div></div>
```

The behavior you seek can be achieved with HTML that's what it's for.
Notice I used no CSS for the positioning and let HTML do all the work.
check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCXjr/)